# LocustIO always returns Internal Server Error for All Post API calls

Tags: python, load-testing, internal-server-error, locust

I'm using Locust to run a load test, to my surprise all of the POST APIs I tried calling from it returns "Internal Server Error - 500", but if I run the same APIs from JMeter they run well. I checked and saw like LocustIO prepends and apostrophe at the end of each call. This is a screen shot
[image: Locust Failure UI]

This is my setup code:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class justTestApi(TaskSet):

    @task(1)
    def accountInquiry(self):
        self.client.post("/users", {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  });

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = justTestApi
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 9000
    host = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
    stop_timeout = 200
```

Comment: What does your server log show? A 500 is coming back from the server, not from Locust.

Comment: Locust is passing apostrophe and comma to the end of the endpoint that's the problem, and I don't know why. An example is this: ```https://myapp.com/users',``` This is what it is sending as the endpoint.

Comment: That `'` is the closing apostrophe to the beginning of the error string... which clearly articulates the error in question...

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it working using this tutorial - https://andrew-jones.com/blog/load-testing-with-locust/. This is how the setup should look like when trying to test a post restful call. I read an argument that LocustIO can't be used to test https, this test faulted that claim. It can be used to test https as well.

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

json = """
[{
  userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: "quidem molestiae enim"
}]
"""

class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def send(l):
        l.client.post("/albums", json) 

class MyLocust(HttpLocust):
    task_set = MyTaskSet
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 15000
    # host = "http://www.somaku.com"
    host = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
    stop_timeout = 200
```

Comment: This suggests you were sending invalid json to your service. Thus the 500 response.